# awk: filter a file with another file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to filter a file with another file. 
I have a file d3_tmp and m2p_tmp; They are as follows:

```
$ cat d3_tmp 
0x000001     0x4d    2
0x1107ce     0x4e    2
0x111deb     0x6b    2

$ cat m2p_tmp 
mfn=0x000001 ==> pfn=0xffffffffffffffff
mfn=0x000002 ==> pfn=0xffffffffffffffff
mfn=0x000003 ==> pfn=0xffffffffffffffff
```

I want to print out the lines in m2p_tmp whose second column is not equal to the first column of d3_tmp. (The files are split with \t and =)

So the desired result is:

```
  mfn=0x000002 ==> pfn=0xffffffffffffffff
  mfn=0x000003 ==> pfn=0xffffffffffffffff
```

However, after I use the following awk command:

```
awk -F '[\t=]' ' FNR==NR { print $1; a[$1]=1; next } !($2 in a){printf "%s \t 0\n", $2}'     d3_tmp  m2p_tmp
```

The result is:

```
0x000001  
0x1107ce  
0x111deb  
0x000001     0
0x000002     0
0x000003     0
```

I'm not sure why "$2 in a" does not work. 
Could anyone help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a trailing space.  `0x000002 ` != `0x000002`

Comment: Thank you so much William! I got it!

Comment: You changed the topic, the source file is in different format now. Can you discuss in new request ? Otherwise, it will confuse others, if they see the solution which were provided.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i];next} !($2 in a)' d3_tmp FS="[ =]" m2p_tmp
```

a[$i] is used to collect all items in file d3_tmp into array a, NR==FNR used to control the collection is only focus on d3_tmp. 
in second part, set the FS to space or "=", and compare if $2 in file m2p_tmp is in this array a or not, if in, print it.

The question has been edited, so I have to change the code as well.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($2 in a)' d3_tmp FS="[ \t=]" m2p_tmp
```

Comment: That is quite amusing. Could you explain about !($2 in a)? Where does this a come from? and what does !(...) mean?

Comment: it means the item in second column is not in the array a.

Comment: @yaeyong, put some explanation, please check

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FS="[\t= ]"  ' FNR==NR { a[$1]=$1; next } !($2 in a){print $0}'     d3_tmp  m2p_tmp
mfn=0x000002 ==> pfn=0xffffffffffffffff
mfn=0x000003 ==> pfn=0xffffffffffffffff
```